# Django mod-python error

Tags: python, django

Can someone please tell what this strange error is

```
 Mod_python error: "PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython"

 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 287, in HandlerDispatch
log=debug)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 464, in import_module
  module = imp.load_module(mname, f, p, d)

 File "/project/django/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 4, in ?
  from django import http

File "/project/django/django/http/__init__.py", line 3, in ?
 from Cookie import SimpleCookie, CookieError

 ImportError: No module named Cookie


 Edit:
  Python   
 Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan 14 2008, 18:32:40) 
 [GCC 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> from Cookie import SimpleCookie, CookieError
  >>> from http.Cookie import SimpleCookie, CookieError
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  ImportError: No module named http.Cookie
 >>> import Cookie
 >>> import http.Cookie
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
 ImportError: No module named http.Cookie
 >>> import http.Cookie
```

Comment: What does your mod_python config look like?  Are you modifying PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you're missing the Cookie package (which is not part of Django), but it should be Builtin.

If you're using Python 3 please note that `Cookie` has been renamed to `http.cookies`, and that Django is incompatible with Python not 2.x.

That is what you're missing: http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html.

## Edit

I see you're running python 2.4. Consider switch to python 2.6 or 2.7, and check the presence of `/usr/lib/python2.4/Cookie.py`

## Solution

The path was missing, so adding

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.4/')
```

solves the issue.

Comment: The file /usr/lib/python2.4/Cookie.py is present

Comment: Maybe django is overwriting for some reason your python path. What about doing something like sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.4/') in your settings.py or urls.py? Or in your cgi provider. I know it's a stupid try, but no other ideas...

Comment: It was sys.path, that was missing in the python path..thanks for the lead